# Set state for only for self data into map on reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have a object's array of users and i'm using map to show them, each user have a option buttons that is 'edit' and 'remove' options each option have a onlclick function that set a state to show another view so the code explain itselft

```
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
        edit: false,
        remove: false
    }

    handleEdit = () => {
        this.setState({ edit: true })
    }

    handleRemove = () => {
        this.setState({ remove: true })
    }

    cancelEdit = () => {
        this.setState({ edit: false })
    }

    cancelRemove = () => {
        this.setState({ remove: false })
    }

    renderEditItem = () => {
        const {
            state: {
                edit,
                remove
            },
            cancelEdit,
            cancelRemove,
            handleEdit,
            handleRemove
        } = this

        if (edit) {
            return (
                <div>
                    <span>Edit view</span>
                    <br/>
                    <button onClick={cancelEdit}>Cancel</button>
                </div>
            )
        }

        if (remove) {
            return (
                <div>
                    <span>Remove view</span>
                    <br/>
                    <button onClick={cancelRemove}>Cancel</button>                  
                </div>
            )
        }

        return (
            <div>
                <button onClick={handleEdit}>Edit</button>
                <br/>
                <button onClick={handleRemove}>Remove</button>
            </div>
        )
    }


    renderUsers = () => {
        const {
            renderEditItem
        } = this

        const users = [
            {
                id: 1,
                name: 'User1'
            },
            {
                id: 2,
                name: 'User-2'
            },
            {
                id: 3,
                name: 'User-3'
            }
        ]

        return users.map((user) => {
            return (
                <ul key={user.id}>
                    <li>
                        <div>
                            <span ref='span'>{user.name}</span>
                            <br/>
                            {renderEditItem()}
                        </div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            )
        })
    }

    render () {
        return (
            <div>
                {this.renderUsers()}
            </div>
        )
    }
}

React.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('app')
);
```

JSfiddle: [Here](https://fiddle.jshell.net/juanX/ebtjoLj5/2/)

The issue is how can you see is, when i click on the button to set the state for edit or remove option, this will show the view for all the items,
and should be only the view that is clicked, i know the state change to true and is the same for all the items but i don't know how to set the state only for one entry any idea?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that the edit/remove state is singular and for the entire list. Each item in the list receives the same state here:

```
if (edit) {
    return (
        <div>
            <span>Edit view</span>
            <br/>
            <button onClick={cancelEdit}>Cancel</button>
        </div>
    )
}
```

The single `edit` variable from the state is applied to each list item. If you want to individually set the edit state for each item, it will need to be kept track of with that item.

EX:

```
const users = [
    {
        id: 1,
        name: 'User1',
        edit: true
    }]
```

This way each individual item will be able to tell what state it is in individually. User1 item will have an edit mode that is independent of the other users.

Then you can render something like this:

```
return users.map((user) => {
    return (
        <ul key={user.id}>
            <li>
                <div>
                    <span ref='span'>{user.name}</span>
                    <br/>
                    {user.edit ? 'EDIT MODE' : 'NOT EDIT MODE'}
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    )
})
```

Comment: Thanks, and i noticed that there are another way to do this without add something else in the object, and is convert to component Whatever you want to return into the map function, with this way, the onClick fnc only will trigger the state into the component scope.